# Any npm's command is not working

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I can attach the error log file

---

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'config' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@1.4.28
>
> 3 info using node@v0.10.35
>
> 4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
>
> 5 error Error: ENOENT, stat 'c:\'C:\Program'
>
> 6 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
>
> 6 error including the npm and node versions, at:
>
> 6 error     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> 7 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> 8 error command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "config"
>
> 9 error cwd c:\
>
> 10 error node -v v0.10.35
>
> 11 error npm -v 1.4.28
>
> 12 error path c:\'C:\Program
>
> 13 error code ENOENT
>
> 14 error errno 34
>
> 15 verbose exit [ 34, true ]

---

Any npm's command is not working.

I am using `windows 8.1` and I installed npm successfully.

I heard that ENOENT error can be fixed if I make a folder relate to the error path but

error path contains 'C:\Program, I cannot make that file.

How can I solve this problem? I tried to uninstall npm, I failed.

This problem happened because I tried to change prefix for npm but something goes wrong

Comment: It looks like Node doesn't like being installed in a location with spaces in the name. This isn't particular unusual, since it uses `/usr/local` by default, at least on Unix (including Linux and OSX). Still, bummer.

Answer (score 1):

I found way to fix it.

OK, the reason why this problem happened was that I usually use CMD with administrator's admission.

Because of that setting, actually, I don't need to change prefix of npm but I just want to practice what I learn in my current book.

So I tried to change prefix but accidentally, Using

```
npm config set prefix C:\program files
```

I changed the prefix 'C:\program' like this.

because of special character : , I cannot create name of fold including : .

because of damn prefix, npm was totally not working.

I searched npm folder, I found npmrc file but it did not help.

Finally, I found .npmrc at C:\Users\myName .

there, the prefix was setted at C:\program .

I delete prefix and Now it is working!!!!!

Bye Bye let's master nodejs